# Updating SQL Table with the changes made to an in-memory datatable

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, datatable

I have a table in an SQL database (on a local network) with 5,000+ rows. This data is loaded into an in-memory datatable in a client application I'm developing for end-users to view, search and manipulate records.

My question is **once the user is finished manipulating the data, what is the best way to write it back to the SQL table?** I could clear the SQL table and send the entire in-memory datatable to the SQL server, but given the large number of records, this seems like a dodgy and inefficient process.

Does anyone have a solution that comes to mind? For instance, somehow tracking the records that are changed by the user and only updating those ones through an SQL query?

What would be the best way to handle this? I'm happy to completely re-think my approach if necessary.

Comment: [SqlDataAdapter.Update](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1z2bkx2(v=vs.110).aspx) and about _tracking changes_ do not reinvent the wheel. [DataRow.RowState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for the guidance. This is the first time I've done anything like this but it sounds like exactly what I need. Thanks again

Comment: With lots of records a DataAdapter can be slow. If you run into bottle necks consider saving the whole DataTable to a temportary table (E.g. Select * Into #MyTemp From YourTableName), use SqlBulkCopy to save the data to it and then use the MERGE statement to get the database to apply your changes,

Comment: Thanks Ciarán. I might find myself running into this issue so I'll keep this solution in mind. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you configure your data set, you can define an update statement that is appropriate for your needs.

The datatable you are manipulating will track its own changes, and you can grab them using the `GetChanges` method. When you call the adapter's `Update` function you can send the datatable's changes only.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2552649%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.update%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

SqlDataAdapter.Update and about tracking changes do not reinvent the wheel. DataRow.RowState –  Steve